# Generating a jar with the source code of the Maven project with the Maven directory structure?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, build

I have a web application that I build with Maven into a war. But I want to generate a JAR with the maven project with the correct maven directory structure. I tried [this](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/) but it throws away the Maven directory structure (src/main/java, etc.). My goal is to distribute this jar to other people so they can unpack and run mvn eclipse:eclipse and start working on their new web project.

Comment: Are you sure that's the best way to distribute a project?

Comment: Yeah, it is a template project.

Comment: Maybe you can build an archetype out of it, actually archetypes are meant for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using the existing descriptor of [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#src)..

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
</configuratio
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven-assembly-plugin. It's pretty straight-forward to do what you want.

Here's your definition for the plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-distribution</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
<descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Here's your src/main/assembly/assembly.xml:

```
<assembly>

        <id>my-project</id>

        <formats>
                <format>zip</format>
        </formats>

        <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

        <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                                <include>**/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                </fileSet>
        </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

I haven't tested it, but it's roughly the way you should set it up.

Comment: Another annoying problem is that it includes the base directory no matter what you do. /myapp/src/main/java/ etc. I just want src/main/java

Comment: Karl-Heinz' solution should also work, it's just a less descriptive example. You can drop the assembly.xml, if you know what you're doing. This was just a simple example.

Comment: Check this page http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html and fix the fileSet as per your needs. You can define an `outputDirectory`.