# Generating jar of a maven project with all sources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to generate a jar which contains all the source files,test classes, resources, dependencies, extra source directories of a maven project.

Can anyone please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question (I won't say its a complete dup) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263859/generating-a-jar-with-the-source-code-of-the-maven-project-with-the-maven-direct?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `maven-source-plugin`. This will create a sources.jar during `mvn install`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the [`jar-no-fork`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-no-fork-mojo.html) goal instead otherwise the [life cycle is forked](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html).